# Upload images with dropzonejs and CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, upload

I would like to drag and drop many images with pop-up of CakePHP3. I tried dropzonejs.com but dropzonejs is using action of form to upload images directly.
I would like to put these upload images and another input elements in the form of .ctp file.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: Dropzone works even on non form elements and input elements, you just have to specify url... Read [dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#usage) docs.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://www.dropzonejs.com):

Alternatively you can create dropzones programmaticaly (even on non form elements) by instantiating the Dropzone class:

```
// Dropzone class:
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myId", { url: "/file/post"});

// jQuery
$("div#myId").dropzone({ url: "/file/post" });
```